# RavenPack API_key is working in postman but NOT in python code

Tags: python, api, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, postman

I am tryin to work with this repo https://github.com/RavenPack/python-api

Weirdly enough, the API is working perfectly with POSTMAN (it's a tool used to automate testing API development and HTTP calls)

Here's the code snippet

```
from ravenpackapi import RPApi
from ravenpackapi import Dataset

api = RPApi(
    api_key="_________" //correct api_key was intentionally removed for the post
)

ds = api.create_dataset(
    Dataset(
        name="New Dataset",
        filters={
            "relevance": {
                "$gte": 90
            }
        },
    )
)

print("Dataset created", ds)
```

Here is the error message.

[image]

**I repeat the same API key is working with postman on the same device and network.** It's just that their python library is giving me a hard time.

```
Exception has occurred: APIException
Got an error 401: body was '{"endpoint":"datasets","errors":[{"type":"UnauthorizedError","reason":"Unauthorized: Must supply a valid API key"}]}'
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\Python\RavenPackAPI.py", line 8, in <module>
    ds = api.create_dataset(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/RavenPack/python-api/blob/master/ravenpackapi/examples/create_dataset_edge.py

This code is the solution^^^ I was using an old code snippet that called the RPA cluster internally:

```
from ravenpackapi import RPApi
from ravenpackapi import Dataset

#api = RPApi(api_key="L3KOJd7sjL7ZPsWXt4geSy")



api = RPApi(api_key="L3KOJd7sjL7ZPsWXt4geSy", product="edge")

ds = api.create_dataset(
    Dataset(
        **{
            "name": "Edge Dataset",
            "product": "edge",
            "product_version": "1.0",
            "frequency": "granular",
            "fields": [
                "timestamp_utc", "rp_document_id", "rp_entity_id", "entity_type", "entity_name",
                "country_code", "event_relevance", "entity_sentiment", "event_sentiment", "topic", "group"
            ],
            "filters": {
                "$and": [
                    {"event_relevance": {"$gte": 90}},
                    {"country_code": {"$in": ["GB"]}},
                    {"event_sentiment": {"$nbetween": [-0.5, 0.5]}}
                ]
            },
        }
    )
)

print("Dataset created", ds)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be that you are not pointing to the correct API cluster.  The API Key may only be entitled to the previous product version.

To point to the Edge cluster - set your API with the following code:

```
from ravenpackapi import RPApi

api = RPApi(product="edge")
```

Comment: I set it to Edge and it gave me a 500 server side error.

Comment: Exception has occurred: APIException
Got an error 500: body was '{"errors":[{"type":"InternalError","reason":"An Internal Error occurred"}]}'
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\Python\RavenPackAPI.py", line 9, in <module>
    ds = api.create_dataset(